# Why EJB stateless session bean must not implement SessionSynchronization?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I'm precisely talking about EJB 3.1, and I know that per specifications a stateless session bean must not implement the `SessionSynchronization` interface, but could someone explain to me why ? So, I am not asking for a workaround but I would like to know the reasons behind this restristion.

### UPDATE:

I don't think this is related to transaction boundaries, because the container should commit when the business method has completed, as per section 13.6.2.2:

> The container attempts to commit the transaction when the business
>   method has completed. The container performs the commit protocol
>   before the method result is sent to the client.

And per [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html):

> Typically, the container begins a transaction immediately before an
>   enterprise bean method starts and commits the transaction just before
>   the method exits. Each method can be associated with a single
>   transaction. Nested or multiple transactions are not allowed within a
>   method.

Answer (score 3):

The question is related to transactions topic. Because stateless session beans (SLSB) do not keep conversational state between subsequent requests then any changes in resource state (e.g. database update) are local in the context of method. Transaction cannot be spanned across multiple methods for SLSB. 
In regard to stateful session bean situation (SFSB) is a bit different. This is not mandatory to complete transaction before method ends. Therefore transaction can span multiple methods. 
When you let the container to manage transactions (CMT) and use SFSB there is possibility that you do not know precisely when transaction is started/completed. You need a mechanism that notifies when those actions happen. And this is `SessionSynchronization` interface implementation purpose. 
SLBSs with CMT do not receive transaction start/end notification because transaction boundaries are known and they are limited to a business method execution.

Comment: thanks but this is not what the specifications said, could you show me that in specs "This is not mandatory to complete transaction before method ends" ?

Comment: I cannot show you literally because those words are mine. However plase take a look at: "In the case of a stateful session bean, it is possible that the business method that started a transaction
completes without committing or rolling back the transaction" This is from chapter 13.6.1 of EJB 3.1 spec. Take a look also at a diagram in chapter 4.6. and "method ready in TX"  block.

Comment: The specs section you mentionned is about Bean-Managed Transaction Demarcation, which is not our case because you can't implement SessionSynchronization from BMT's. Here we are talking about CMT's

Comment: But the diagram concerns both CMT and BMT.

Comment: Nothing on the diagram is related to that! I can't see how you can figure transaction boundaries from that diagram

Comment: Take a look at `afterBegin()` `beforeCompletion()` `afterCompletion()` methods. And can you see "method ready in TX" block? And curved arrow sticked to it?

Comment: I'am on the specs and I saw what you are talking about, but this doens't mean the container will not commit before the method return! it will commit when then ?! I mentionned in my question clear sentences from the specs that the container will commit after method complete. And this is for all kind of CMT session Beans

Comment: @Tarik That's only true for REQUIRES_NEW.  For MANDATORY and REQUIRED, the EJB container will only commit the transaction at the end of the method if it started the transaction, not if it just joined a pre-existing transaction.  The EJB spec could in theory allow stateless session beans to implement SessionSynchronization but only invoke the callbacks if the bean method started the transaction, but I suspect that will not happen due to the high conceptual complexity.  The instance is stateless, so I guess it would need to access data from TransactionSynchronizationRegistry?

Comment: `Transaction cannot be spanned across multiple methods for SLSB` - this is not true.

Comment: @BrettKail you are right, but could you explain more about the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry?

Comment: @Tarik putResource/getResource would allow the SLSB to store "transaction local" state without storing it in the bean instance.  That way, the container could return the actual bean instance to the pool at the end of the method and then obtain a new one when the transaction finally ends if that's not coincident with the end of the method.